DC Electronics Load Part Capacity
Sure, here's your question translated into English:
I'm working on developing a DC electronics load that I intend to discharge at up to 30V and 60A. For this, I'm using the FBSOA MOSFET IXTN200N10L2, with each circuit handling 20A to manage heat dissipation .

However, while looking at Fig. 7. Input Admittance on page 4 of the MOSFET's datasheet, I came across something confusing. According to this graph, at 40 degrees, approximately 6.75V of Vgs is required to conduct 20A.

As you can see in my circuit, feedback is received through the shunt resistor. Assuming a shunt resistor of 325mOhm, a control voltage of about 6.5V is generated for 20A.

The problem is, even if the resistors are used in parallel, each shunt resistor will dissipate around 65W of power. Am I calculating this correctly?
I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if I'm misunderstanding the specifications. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your continuous support.
I'm not very familiar with analog circuits, so this might be a silly question. But I read all the comments, so thank you again!

What is the source of the energy you want to discharge and for how long will you be discharging 60A @ 30V ? Is it milliseconds or something more substantial ? If it is constant it will be approximately equivalent to a 2kw electric heater.

In reality, it will be about 12V 4-50A, and we will try to discharge the lead acid battery.
Maybe for an several hour

Does control voltage have to be 6.5V? It seems an arbitrary choice. You seem to have used the transfer function wrong, 6.7V is ~110A; also, what relevance is Vgs, you mention it but don't seem to use it?

The table appears correct if you are discharging 10A at 6.5volts [through a 650mOhm resistor]. The dissipated power is I * I * R or V * I. The RDS(on) for that MOSFET (11mOhms) is quoted at 10v so the gate voltage should not be lower. By control voltage, do you mean the mosfet gate voltage or the momentary voltage of the battery you are discharging ?

Thanks Bro, I've totally misunderstand that sheet.
I added the reply for answer

I think I have roughly solved the problem. After running a Pspice simulation, I realized that the important factor is the ratio between the shunt resistor and the input resistance, not just the simple values.


I believe the simulation will be accurate as I used the manufacturer's model in Pspice.
For now, I think I will use the following values
I'm not sure if anyone else will have the same curiosity, but I'll leave this here for reference.
Wishing everyone a happy day.

Your question needs fixing so that anyone reading this answer can stand a chance of understanding what your question is all about.
